# How to transform camera calibration parameters to other coordinate system?

Tags: coordinate-system, c++, mathematics, photogrammetry

I have all camera calibration parameters (X0, Y0, focal length, R0, P0, P1, K0, K1, coarse rotation, rotation, translation) and position of the image in WGS84 (XYZ in meters) and other parameters like fi (azimuth), omega, kappa.

I have laser points in the coordinates system different than WGS84, so each time when I want to check if the point is in the image I need to transform my point into the WGS84 coordinate system.
To avoid unnecessary calculations I want to transform my position of the image to coordinate system like in my laser data.

The problem is that I also need to transform camera calibration parameters and fi, omega and kappa. I don't know which exactly values need to be transformed and how I can achieve it.

I'm not asking about the soft, but the method to do that because I need to implement this solution to my program. Also, I can't transform image position before calculate camera calibration parameters, because I will only have final values.

The question is: what parameters I need to transform and which mathematical formulas I need to use?

I've tried to figure it out myself, but unfortunately, I don't have enough knowledge about it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is `7-parameters Helmert Transformation`.
Using this transformation I can easily transform rotations for each camera separately.